# Can you make a custom timeline?

Tags: ms-project, gantt, timeline

Can you make  a custom timeline by corporate periods? or add the periods over the dates?

Our company refers to time in Periods where each period has 4 weeks. Is it possible to remove the dates or add the period distinction maybe above the timeline?

Thanks,
Lori

Answer (score 1):

You can change the format of the dates in the timescale (area above Gantt chart) but you cannot define your own time periods, nor add custom text.

I'd suggest using Middle Tier in Weeks with the label of Week 1, Week 2 or something similar.  Right click on the timescale and choose Timescale from the shortcut menu.